# Give a notificiation when you disconnect from a specific wifi network

Tags: java, android, xml

I need my application to give a notification whenever **a specific** WiFi goes offline.

I got it to give a notification every time the WiFi connection disconnects. But I need it to only give a notification when **a specific** WiFi network disconnects. Is my code suitable for this? I read something about class wifiinfo, is this the solution?

My question is, how do I alter the code to only give a notification when **a specific** WiFi goes offline? Any help in the right direction would be nice! Some examples would be even more awesome.

Thanks in advance!

(Eventually I need a button and when you press this the specific wifi your on atm will become that specific wifi when you disconnect from it you get a notification. If that makes sense.)

The code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    this.registerReceiver(this.mConnReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hoofdmenu);        
}

private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(!isNetworkConnectionAvailable(context)){
            showNotification();
        }

        }
};

public static boolean isNetworkConnectionAvailable(Context context)
  {
      boolean isNetworkConnectionAvailable = false;

      ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService("connectivity");
      NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

      if(activeNetworkInfo != null) 
      {
          isNetworkConnectionAvailable = activeNetworkInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED;
      }
      return isNetworkConnectionAvailable;
  }
```

Comment: This question already discussed dude..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119607/how-to-be-notified-on-wifi-network-status-change

Comment: That's not the same question.

Answer (score 0):

To detect SSID changes, listen for [WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION), grab the SSID from the intent extra [WifiManager.EXTRA_BSSID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#EXTRA_BSSID).

See: [Execute code when wifi SSID changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734055/execute-code-when-wifi-ssid-changes/19738189)